# Need advice on how to distribute computing jobs using Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, distributed, jobs

I have a process like this:

- Start out with around 50,000 record
- Make an API call for each of the 50,000 records and save the resulting JSON response to a file, so I end up with 50k files
- Process each file which involves:

  - Parsing the JSON
  - Saving data to MySQL database

I have the scripts prepped to do this. I use a bash script to do the API calls and a PHP script to do the JSON parsing / DB interaction. I've played around on my Macbook with various options and for at least the API calls, it seems like splitting the process into 8 background jobs works the fastest. The slow process in the PHP/DB stuff.

My ultimate goal is to get this process boiled down so that it can be done much faster than it's done now. On my 2-year old Retina Macbook, it takes about 2 hours. On my 2008 Macbook, it takes around 8 or 9 hours. This will ultimately need to be production ready and I'm looking for options on what to do.

I've never done distributed computing or anything like that, so I'm hoping to get some advice on how others with more experience in this than I do would tackle the problem.

I should also add that I really only need to run this process once a day. Longer term, I'd love to have it run continously where I'm constantly pinging the API and updating the DB as needed, but for now it only needs to go once a day. There may be a shorter-term solution to run it 2 to 4 times a day. I guess the point here is that these are "get in, get out" jobs and I don't want to use dedicated 24-hour computing power for them!

My current idea is this:

- Create an Amazon RDS for the database
- Create an Amazon EC2 image that contains my bash script and PHP script
- Create a "controller" EC2 image that uses the AWS CLI tool create EC2 instances using the above image
- The controller also breaks up the 50k records into chunks, where each EC2 instance gets an equal chunk
- Once one of the EC2 images is done with its processing, it tells the controller its done and the controller destorys it

This seems logical to me, but I have no idea if this is a reaosonable approach. It seems like it would work but there may be a stupid simple way of doing this using techniques/technologies I'm ignorant to.

I've love to get some feedback on this!

Comment: This is a perfect application for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/  Using that you could spin up the processes you need and then shut them down when you are done.

Comment: Is the API that you call completely external, or is it a system that you could run yourself and incorporate into the process? It sounds like a potential use-case for Amazon Elastic MapReduce, which manages distributed processing via Hadoop. Very powerful, but rather complex to setup.

Comment: The API is completely external. It's a 3rd party service.